# knife ec2 bootstrap takes forever

Tags: chef-infra, bootstrapping, knife

I am trying to bootstrap my first server with knife-ec2, but it takes forever. If I look at AWS Management Console, the new instance is up and running. And looking at Opscode's Chef-server, the Node isn't there yet.

Any idea of what could be happening??

Here is the snapshot of my console:

```
~$ knife ec2 server create -r "role[base-server]" -G default -N server01 -S keypair.pem

Instance ID: i-90ad818f   
Flavor: t1.micro   
Image: ami-b03590ad   
Region: sa-east-1   
Availability Zone: sa-east-1a   
Security Groups: default   
Tags: Name: webserver01   
SSH Key: myfreepair  

Waiting for instance............   
Private DNS Name: ip-172-31-20-139.sa-east-1.compute.internal   
Private IP Address: 172.31.20.139   
.................................................................................................
.................................................................................................
.................................................................................................
.................................................................................................
..............................................................................................
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the chef client has been setup? /etc/chef/client.rb? Next check the chef log and see if there is a long running process holding up execution. Long chef runs at the start are not uncommon as these would usually install all the software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've seen that behavior, it's been due to the chef client being unable to reach the chef server. Can you check the network connection?

Comment: Yes... my default security group wasn't opening the port 22.